# resolve corrupted pdf files when sending to server in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspdf

I made a pdf from jsPDF, and I sent the pdf to my server, following the pdf generate code

```
function genPDF() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('testDiv')).then(function (canvas) {
            var data = []
            var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
            doc.addImage(img, 'png', 10, 10);
            var pdf = doc.output();

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("data", pdf);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('post', '/receive', true); 
            xhr.send(data);

        });
    }
```

and this is the code in the backend

```
app.post('/receive', function (req, res) {

fs.writeFileSync('./static/document/Document.pdf', req.data);
```

})

pdf creation was successfully done on the server, but when the file was opened an error appeared 'that could not be opened because it was an unsupported file type or had been damaged.'

is there something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are writing anything to the PDF ? Could you check it's size in your file explorer. There might by an issue with the data in  `req.data`.

Comment: yes pdf success is created but cannot be opened, and the size of the file is 1 kb

Comment: and I'm very confused